# Can't login in GUI after re-installing pam

Tags: login, pam

I downloaded pam library and `make-install` it on Ubuntu.

When I login:

- Input the correct password shows "wrong password".
- I can still log in through changing to "change user" mode
- That also in GUI, except there's more than one user name.

In "change user", screen shows message "wrong password" still.
But unlock immediately after shows the message.

I don't know why that happened, of course the shell login also works.

What happened? How can I fix it?